# How to modify a functions internal variables at runtime and pass it to another function?

Tags: dart

Functions in Dart are first-class objects, allowing you to pass them to other objects or functions.

```
void main() {
  
  var shout = (msg) => '  ${msg.toUpperCase()} ';
  
  print(shout("yo"));
}
```

This made me wonder if there was a way to modify a function a run time, just like an object, prior to passing it to something else. For example:

```
Function add(int input) {
  return add + 2;
}
```

If I wanted to make the function a generic addition function, then I would do:

```
Function add(int input, int increment) {
  return add + increment;
}
```

But then the problem would be that the object I am passing the function to would need to specify the increment. I would like to pass the add function to another object, with the increment specified at run time, and declared within the function body so that the increment cannot be changed by the recipient of the function object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be to use a lexical closure.

From here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#built-in-types

> A closure is a function object that has access to variables in its
> lexical scope, even when the function is used outside of its original
> scope.
>
> Functions can close over variables defined in surrounding scopes. In
> the following example, makeAdder() captures the variable addBy.
> Wherever the returned function goes, it remembers addBy.

```
/// Returns a function that adds [addBy] to the
/// function's argument.
Function makeAdder(int addBy) {
  return (int i) => addBy + i;
}

void main() {
  // Create a function that adds 2.
  var add2 = makeAdder(2);

  // Create a function that adds 4.
  var add4 = makeAdder(4);

  assert(add2(3) == 5);
  assert(add4(3) == 7);
}
```

In the above cases, we pass 2 or 4 into the makeAdder function. The makeAdder function uses the parameter to create and return a function object that can be passed to other objects.

Answer (score 0):

## Using partial function application

You can use a [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) to bind arguments to functions.

If you have something like:

```dart
int add(int input, int increment) => input + increment;
```

and want to pass it to another function that expects to supply fewer arguments:

```dart
int foo(int Function(int input) applyIncrement) => applyIncrement(10);
```

then you could do:

```dart
foo((input) => add(input, 2); // `increment` is fixed to 2
foo((input) => add(input, 4); // `increment` is fixed to 4
```

## Using callable objects

Another approach would be to make [a callable object](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes):

```dart
class Adder {
  int increment = 0;

  int call(int input) => input + increment;
}
```

which could be used with the same `foo` function above:

```dart
var adder = Adder()..increment = 2;
print(foo(adder)); // Prints: 12

adder.increment = 4;
print(foo(adder)); // Prints: 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't need to *modify* a closure, just the ability to create customized closures.

The latter is simple:

```dart
int Function(int) makeAdder(int increment) => (int value) => value + increment;
...
   foo(makeAdder(1));  // Adds 1.
   foo(makeAdder(4));  // Adds 2.
```

You can't change which variables a closure is referencing, but you can change their values ... if you an access the variable. For local variables, that's actually hard.
Mutating state which makes an existing closure change behavior can *sometimes* be appropriate, but those functions should be very precise about how they change and where they are being used. For a function like `add` which is used for its behavior, changing the behavior is rarely a good idea. It's better to replace the closure in the specific places that need to change behavior, and not risk changing the behavior in other places which happen to depend on the same closure. Otherwise it becomes very important to control where the closure actually flows.

If you still want to change the behavior of an existing global, you need to change a variable that it depends on.

Globals are easy:

```dart
int increment = 1;
int globalAdder(int value) => value + increment;

...
  foo(globalAdd);  // Adds 1.
  increment = 2;
  foo(globalAdd);  // Adds 2.
```

I really can't recommend mutating global variables. It scales rather badly. You have no control over anything.

Another option is to use an *instance* variable to hold the modifiable value.

```dart
class MakeAdder {
  int increment = 1;
  int instanceAdd(int value) => value + increment;
}
...
var makeAdder = MakeAdder();
var adder = makeAdder.instanceAdd;
...
  foo(adder);  // Adds 1.
  makeAdder.increment = 2;
  foo(adder);  // Adds 2.
```

That gives you much more control over who can access the increment variable. You can create multiple independent mutaable adders without them stepping on each other's toes.

To modify a local variable, you need someone to give you access to it, from inside the function where the variable is visible.

```dart
int Function(int) makeAdder(void Function(void Function(int)) setIncrementCallback) {
  var increment = 1;
  setIncrementCallback((v) {
    increment = v;
  });
  return (value) => value + increment;
}
...
void Function(int) setIncrement;
int Function(int) localAdd = makeAdder((inc) { setIncrement = inc; });
...
 foo(localAdd);  // Adds 1.
 setIncrement(2);
 foo(localAdd);  // Adds 2.
```

This is one way of passing back a way to modify the local increment variable.
It's almost always far too complicated an approach for what it gives you, I'd go with the instance variable instead.

Often, the instance variable will actually represent something in your model, some state which can meaningfully change, and then it becomes predictable and understandable when and how the state of the entire model changes, including the functions referring to that model.